# Autenticacion JWT para Web APP?

Tags: nodejs, aplicación-web, rest

Eh visto que es muy común utilizar la autenticacion basada en token para API's RestFul, la pregunta es, ¿Se puede implementar para una aplicacion Web?

Comment: Json **Web** Tokens

Comment: Puedes usarlo como sesión ya que los tokens pueden expirar. Cuando no te quede claro qué uso le puedes dar a algo, el primer lugar en el que debes consultar es en el sitio oficial.

Answer (score 2):

Si. De hecho, la **W** en JWT es por ***Web***. Mira la documentación: https://jwt.io

Answer (score 1):

Por supuesto
¿Que tiene una aplicación web que no tiene un cliente REST?
El navegador, podría decirse.
Pero los frameworks y tecnologías como React o Vue son clientes REST que hacen llamadas a servicios basados en REST,... 
El modelo de JWT es sin-sesion en servidor y se está imponiendo por sus ventajas en escalabilidad, tambien en aplicaciones web.

Answer (score 0):

JWT se esta volviendo un standar para casi cualquier metodo de autenticacion, te lo recomiendo, y este articulo te puede ayudar.
[Introduccion a JWT - Platzi](https://platzi.com/blog/introduccion-json-web-tokens/)